# Google meet link open from webview to meet android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have an app which is basicall a webview of my website. In which i have done google meet integration. Now for creating a meeting i needed older version of chrome as a browser agent. So now creation of google meeting is working fine.
But the problem is when i m trying to join the meeting i.e to open the meet link in webview its giving me error saying "this browser is no longer supported".

I want this link to be opened in google meet app. And if that app is not der then to redirect it to play store to download it.
Plz help.
Or atleast to open google meet in the tab.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = mWebView.getUrl();

            String googleMeetUrlPattern = "(?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:meet\\.google\\.com\\/|plus\\.google\\.com\\/hangouts\\/_)\\S+";

            // Check if the URL matches the pattern
            if (url.matches(googleMeetUrlPattern)) {
                // Open the URL in the Google Meet/ Zoom app
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening Meet App..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true; // Return true to indicate that the URL has been handled
            }

            // Return false to let the WebView handle the URL loading
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.